# Prediction of a crash of the Operating System

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ubuntu, operating-system

I am not studying operating systems in particular, so I thought maybe I should ask the experts about my curiosity.

My Linux machine has been crashing/freezing very often (to be fair, due to heavy tasks being run simultaneously) recently, and this is frustrating. As a programmer, I was wondering how difficult it would be for the task manager of the OS to predict when the tasks being passed to it are about to exceed the capacity of the system. Is it impossible to stop all the non-major processes for a moment and suggest the user that they should perhaps terminate some of the task to avoid a crash? Like, "hey, how about you close your YouTube tab before I process 1000 of your 4k images that you just commanded!" This prediction is not much of a prediction though, since even one second before the crash it can handle the situation.

Is there any limitation for this functionality?

Comment: My first instinct is to point out that the function of the task-scheduler in an operating system is already to do this very thing. What you're calling a 'crash' could possibly be the system becoming unresponsive due to some failure of time sharing on behalf of the task-scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux **top** command is used to show all the running processes within your Linux environment. this command can give prediction about your server process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but manually monitoring the processes and deciding whether or not we (the user) should run the next process is not what I asked.